# Fetch database results by choosing dropdown option

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a small problem with my filtering system I'm creating.
I have a dropdown with database categories and one category is "Alle" (english: All) and is chosen by default. This option is not in the database but a separate html option.

This is the filter
[image: .]

When I open the filter first I see all my database results (because i have a PHP code to show all results if nothing happens at first) but when I choose a random category and then choose "Alle" again there is just an error.

Here is the error
[image: .]

Someone know a script (ajax) and php code to show all results by clicking on "all".

Here are my codes:

index.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">
<head>

<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>


  
  $(document).ready(function(){

    // Live anzeigen der 2. Ebene + 1 Ebene Ergebnisse
    $('#category').on('change', function(){
      var categoryID = $(this).val();
      if(categoryID){
        $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url:'ajaxdata.php',
          data:'category_id='+categoryID,
          success:function(html){
            $('#subcategory').html(html);
            $('#partner').html(html);
            $('#subcategory').prop('disabled', false);
          }
        });
      } else {
        $('#subcategory').html('<option value="">Zuerst Überkategorie auswählen!</option>');
      }
    }); 

    // Live Anzeigen der 3. Ebene + 2. Ebene Ergebnisse
    $('#subcategory').on('change', function(){
      var subcategoryID = $(this).val();
      if(subcategoryID){
        $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url:'ajaxdata.php',
          data:'subcategory_id='+subcategoryID,
          success:function(html){
            $('#subcategory2').html(html);
            $('#partner').html(html);
            $('#subcategory2').prop('disabled', false);
          }
        });
      } else {
        $('#subcategory2').html('<option value="">Zuerst Unterkategorie 
    auswählen!</option>');
      }
    });

    // Live anzeigen der 3. Ebene Ergebnisse
    $('#subcategory2').on('change', function(){
      var subcategory2ID = $(this).val();
      if(subcategory2ID){
        $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url:'ajaxdata.php',
          data:'subcategory2_id='+subcategory2ID,
          success:function(html){
            $('#partner').html(html);
          }
        });
      } else {
        $('#partner').html('<h1>Zuerst Unterkategorie auswählen!</h1>');
      }
    });
  });

</script>

</head>
<body>
<?php

  // Include connection.php
  include_once 'dbconfig.php';

  // Fetch all the category data
  $query = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY category_name 
 ASC";
  $result = $connect->query($query);

 ?>

 <!-- Category dropdown -->
 <form action="" method="post">
  <select id="category" name="category">
    <option value="all">Alle</option>

    <?php

      if($result->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $result->FETCH_ASSOC()){
          echo '<option 
  value="'.$row['category_id'].'">'.$row['category_name'].'</option>';

        }
      } else {
        echo '<option value="">Nicht verfügbar!</option>';
      }
    ?>
  </select>

  <!-- Subcategory dropdown -->
  <select id="subcategory" name="subcategory" disabled>
    <option value="">Kategorie auswählen!</option>
  </select>

  <!-- 2nd subcategory dropdown -->
  <select id="subcategory2" name="subcategory2" disabled>
    <option value="">Kategorie auswählen!</option>
  </select>
 </form>



  <!-- Show all results -->
  <div id="all_results">
      <?
      $query = "SELECT * FROM partner WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY partner_name 
      ASC";
      $result = $connect->query($query);
      if ($result->num_rows > 0){
      }
      ?>
  </div>



<!-- Partner results -->
<div id="partner">
  <?php

    if($result->num_rows > 0){
      while($row = $result->FETCH_ASSOC()){
        ?>
        <div>
          <h1><? echo $row['partner_name'] ?></h1><br>
          <img src="<? echo $row['partner_logo'] ?>"><br>
          <a href="<? echo $row['partner_link'] ?>">Zum Unternehmen!</a>
        </div>
        <?php 
      }
    } else {
      echo '<p>Nichts gefunden!<p>';
    }
   ?>
</div>


<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

ajaxdata.php

```
<?php

include_once 'dbconfig.php';


//Dropdown No. 1
if(!empty($_POST['category_id'])){

// Anzeigen von Ergebnisse - 1. Ebene
$query = "SELECT * FROM partner WHERE category_id = ".$_POST['category_id']." AND status = 1 ORDER BY  partner_name ASC";
$result = $connect->query($query);
if($result->num_rows > 0){
  while($row = $result->FETCH_ASSOC()){
    ?>
    
    <div class="div_results">
      <h1><? echo $row['partner_name'] ?></h1><br>
      <img src="<? echo $row['partner_logo'] ?>"><br>
      <a href="<? echo $row['partner_link'] ?>">Zum Unternehmen!</a>
    </div>
  <?php
  }
}

// Anzeigen der Kategorien der 2. Ebene
$query = "SELECT * FROM subcategories WHERE category_id = ".$_POST['category_id']." AND status = 1 ORDER BY subcategory_name ASC";
$result = $connect->query($query);
if($result->num_rows > 0){
  echo '<option value="">Kategorie auswählen!</option>';

  while($row = $result->FETCH_ASSOC()){
    echo '<option value="'.$row['subcategory_id'].'">'.$row['subcategory_name'].'</option>';
  }
}
else {
  echo '<option value="">Nothing found!</option>';
}
}

// Dropdown No. 2
elseif(!empty($_POST['subcategory_id'])){

// Anzeigen von Ergebnisse - 2. Ebene
$query = "SELECT * FROM partner WHERE subcategory_id = ".$_POST['subcategory_id']." AND status = 1 ORDER BY  partner_name ASC";
$result = $connect->query($query);
if($result->num_rows > 0){
  while($row = $result->FETCH_ASSOC()){
    ?>
    
    <div>
      <h1><? echo $row['partner_name'] ?></h1><br>
      <img src="<? echo $row['partner_logo'] ?>"><br>
      <a href="<? echo $row['partner_link'] ?>">Zum Unternehmen!</a>
    </div>
  <?php
  }
}

// Anzeigen der Kategorien der 3. Ebene
$query = "SELECT * FROM subcategories2 WHERE subcategory_id = ".$_POST['subcategory_id']." AND status = 1 ORDER BY subcategory2_name ASC";
$result = $connect->query($query);

if($result->num_rows > 0){
  echo '<option value="">Untekategorie auswählen!</option>';

  while($row = $result->FETCH_ASSOC()){
    echo '<option value="'.$row['subcategory2_id'].'">'.$row['subcategory2_name'].'</option>';
  }
}
else {
  echo '<option value="">Nichts gefunden!</option>';
}
}


// Dropdown No. 3
elseif(!empty($_POST['subcategory2_id'])){

// Anzeigen von Ergebnisse - 3. Ebene (Letzte Ebene)
$query  = "SELECT * FROM partner WHERE subcategory2_id = ".$_POST['subcategory2_id']." AND status = 1 ORDER BY partner_name ASC";
$result = $connect->query($query);

if($result->num_rows > 0){

  while($row = $result->FETCH_ASSOC()){
    ?>
    <div>
      <h1><? echo $row['partner_name'] ?></h1><br>
      <img src="<? echo $row['partner_logo'] ?>"><br>
      <a href="<? echo $row['partner_link'] ?>">Zum Unternehmen!</a>
    </div>
    <?php
  }
} else {
  echo 'Nothing found!';
}
}

?>
```

Thanks

Comment: The error sort of speaks for itself, but you need to share the code in your `ajaxdata.php` for us to be more specific.

Comment: Try setting the select value to "\*" (asterisk) i.e. '<option value="*">Alle</option>`

Comment: You probably need a special case in your PHP code which checks for the "All" option being selected and makes sure that you then don't set the relevant parameter and section of your query's WHERE clause in the SQL you send to the database. I say "probably", because we can't see any of your code and therefore can't tell you precisely what you need to do. There's no "general" script to do this kind of thing which can we just hand over to you - the exact code needed will always depend on exactly how you've implemented your search functionality to begin with.

Comment: P.S. As a general point, since you're new to the site I suggest you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) which you were recommended to do when you signed up for StackOverflow (but I can see from your profile that you haven't) and read the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. That way you'll have a better idea of what a good question looks like, and then you can update yours to improve its quality, and so improve your chances of getting an answer. These resources are here to help you have a good experience on StackOverflow, so please use them. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Now: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli. Parameterising your queries will also greatly reduce the risk of accidental syntax errors as a result of un-escaped input values. That is exactly what's happening to you here in fact - if you're sending "all" as the category ID, instead of a number, then when it's naively injected into the SQL you'll end up with `WHERE category_id = all` which obviously creates a SQL syntax error because there are no quote marks round the word `all`...

Comment: I'm gonna take care about security when the filter works to 100% but thanks for the information.

Comment: ...And it's also nonsensical because it will never return any results. As I suspected, you need to write an `if` statement in your PHP to check for this special case - if the category ID is "all" then don't include the `category_id = ...` part of the query at all in the SQL, because you actually don't want any restrictions on that field.

Comment: _"I'm gonna take care about security when the filter works"_ ...this is a bad idea, because you'll just get all of it "working", and then you'll have to immediately re-write and re-test all of your SQL-related code in order to make it secure. Why would you want to do everything twice? Get into good habits now, write it the secure way from the start and then you won't have any re-work to do afterwards. (And as I mentioned, it can also help to take care of some other kinds of bugs on the way, potentially.)

Comment: Oh I didn't knew that. I am new into this and first of all I want functionality. Like learning by doing first. I have never had lessons in PHP or AJAX or something like this so I am learning by myself. I have to say it's not easy...

Comment: And how should I write the if statement? Now I have only statements to get results if the dropdown are not empty. But how do I write an If statement like "if(option value = "all"){" or something like this?

Comment: No, programming isn't easy, it takes time and effort to understand and master all the different aspects. Don't worry about that, just take your time and do it one step at a time. Your attempt so far isn't _bad_ or anything, it just doesn't quite cover everything that you need yet.

Comment: Yeah `if ($_POST['category_id'] == "all")` is what you would need to detect the "all" status being submitted.

Comment: But then I must have an "all" category in the database or not? Bc this statement would not work with the html option "all" or do I think wrong?

Comment: And you build up the SQL string gradually, not all in one go, so you can leave bits out if you need to. e.g. something like this: `$query = "SELECT * FROM partner WHERE"; if ($_POST['category_id'] != "all") { $query .= " AND category_id = ?"; }  $query .= " AND status = 1 ORDER BY  partner_name ASC";`

Comment: _"I must have an "all" category in the database "_ , no that absolutely makes no sense at all from a data perspective. Like I said earlier, the trick is to simply not run a filter on that field whenever "all" is selected. See my comment just above, I've outlined the basic idea.

Comment: Can i write something like if ($_POST['<option value="">']  == "all")

Comment: (I've edited it, so if you're reading right now please just refresh it). The idea is it only includes the "category_id" bit if the user selected an option which isn't "all".

Comment: Oh ok I will try this

Comment: `$_POST['<option value="">'] == "all"`...no, because the HTML "option value" stuff isn't what's sent to the server. It's the data contained within the "value" attribute of the selected option which is actually submitted, and it will use the "name" of the dropdown as the index in $_POST. You've got `<option value="all">Alle</option>` as one of your options in the "category_id" dropdown. Therefore if the user selects this option, then $_POST["category_id"] will contain "all". If they select a different option, it will contain that value. I've already shown you this about 5 comments ago, anyway.

Comment: Can you write the code as an answer? I can't understand anything in this small lines.

Comment: Ok I wrote a summary below, please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write an if statement in your PHP to check for this special case - if the category ID is "all" then you must not include the `category_id = ...` part of the query at all in the SQL, because in that case you actually don't want any restrictions on that field.

e.g.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM partner WHERE"; 
if ($_POST['category_id'] != "all") { $query .= " category_id = ? AND"; }  
$query .= " status = 1 ORDER BY  partner_name ASC";

$stmt = $connect->prepare($query);
if ($_POST['category_id'] != "all") { $stmt->bind_param("i", $_POST["category_id"]); }
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

N.B. I have used a prepared statement and parameterisation here, instead of concatenating `$_POST["category_id"]` directly into the SQL string. This will protect your code from both SQL injection attacks and certain kinds of unexpected SQL syntax errors which can arise from the content of the variable data. You can find more examples of writing secure queries [here](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223122/discussion-on-answer-by-adyson-fetch-database-results-by-choosing-dropdown-optio).